# Looking for an ERD for this three-way relationship

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, cardinality, er-diagram

I am wondering if this can be modeled accurately with an ERD:

> Each Medal is awarded to only one Player of each winning Team.

Answer (score 1):

In other words:

- Each Medal is won by one Team and one Player.
- Each Player plays for one Team and is awarded zero to many Medals.
- Each Team wins zero to many Medals, each Medal going to one player.

[image: Entity relationship diagram]

Comment: thanks for your quick response.
This does not to seem to cover that the player receiving the award should be a member of the team receiving it (plus, teams do not receive a medal, only players do, according to the statement.) Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to respond and then it got off my radar. In my model, the player intentionally does not need to be a (current) member of the team receiving the medal. I was assuming players can switch teams. The fact that a player is a member of a team can be tracked in a different association table.

It is true that player receives the medal, but you might want to track which team the player played for when he won the medal.